# drop down submenu horizontal problems

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am having problems with the drop down menu. I don't want the menu to be the vertical drop down, but the horizontal line submenu. it just isn't working in that the "about" and "contact me" menu link is being pushed to the far right hand side when I don't hover over it, and when I hover over it, the vertical drop down appears

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap_link">
    <div id="toplink">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="tutorials.php">tutorials</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="exams.php">Exams</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="mocks.php">Mocks</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--topLinks -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#toplink {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#toplink ul {
    /*left: 10%;*/
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}
#toplink ul li {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
#toplink li ul {
    /*  display:none;*/
    display:inline;
}
/* decoration for menu and submenu*/
 #toplink ul li a {
    width: 235px;
    line-height:30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left:1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#toplink ul li a:hover {
    background:#aaa;
    color:#fff;
}
#toplink li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#toplink li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size:11px;
}
#toplink li:hover a {
    background:#aaa;
    color:#fff;
}
#toplink li:hover li a:hover {
    background:#777;
    color:#fff;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-top:10px;
    background:#333;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:5px;
    height: 750px;
    text-align:center;
}
body {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/riddleme/4TW4S/)**

Comment: @3dgoo, the drop down maker won't allow me horizontal inline drop down like I want

Comment: @user1869730 - Have you had a look through the list of different menus they have?: http://cssmenumaker.com/ Sorry I meant to send this link before but put in the same link twice instead.

Comment: Here is a horizontal sub menu: http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/811004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `float`, I'd use `display:inline-block` instead.

Change:

```
#toplink ul li {
position: relative;
float:left;
}
```

To:

```
#toplink>ul>li{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4TW4S/1/

More info on inline-blocks vs floats: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

**Update**

For eveything to be horizontal use the following instead:

```
#toplink ul>li{
/*  position: relative;*/
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4TW4S/3/

Comment: Jon, the drop down bit has to be horizontal inline drop down

Comment: Sorry I can't give you reps Jon, this site has a few trolls and people who don't "understand2 yet you clearly understand, thanks for your help